# Meaning of shiji no hoshi

Tags: meaning, translation

I just bought a japanese maple tree - in Oregon, USA - and the variety is listed as 'shiji no hoshi' (English letters, no kanji of course). I know hoshi is star; for shiji Google translate gave me Instruction and Direction. At first I thought direction, i.e. the maple tree will grow in the direction of the stars. But wouldn't that be 'hoshi no shiji'? So I'm still not sure what shiji no hoshi is supposed to be.

Answer (score 3):

Searching in Google ([1](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+maple+%22shiji+no+hoshi%22) -> [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+maple+%22shigi+no+hoshi%22) -> [3](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+maple+%22shigi+no+hoshi%22+%E6%98%9F) -> [4](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%B4%AB%E3%81%AE%E6%98%9F%22)) indicates that "shiji no hoshi" is misspelling for "shigi no hoshi", in Japanese script: 「[鴫](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%B4%AB)の星」.

鴫 means "[sandpiper](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sandpiper) (any of various small wading birds of the family Scolopacidae)".